# NodeJS view results of mongoDB insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, view

I'm trying to learn nodeJS in combination with mongoDB. I'm using the expressJS framework for routing. I've created a connection to a local database and inserting some rows by using the following code.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/sssdb';

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect. Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to:', url);

        var defaultRows = [{'naam':'Test user 1'}, {'naam':'Test user 2'}];
        insertRows(db, 'clients', defaultRows, function(defaultResults) { 
            console.log(defaultResults);

            // Close after insert
            db.close();
        });
    }
});


function insertRows(db, collectionName, data,cb) {
    var collection = db.collection(collectionName);
    collection.insert(data, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Inserted into ' + collectionName);
            cb(res);
        }
    });
}
```

In my terminal I'm running `node app.js` and in an another window a `mongod` shell in the same system map. Everything seems to run fine and my terminal logs:

```
Connected to: mongodb://localhost:27017/sssdb
Inserted into clients
{ result: { ok: 1, n: 2 },
  ops: 
   [ { naam: 'Test user 1', _id: 565570547d27dc440284602d },
     { naam: 'Test user 2', _id: 565570547d27dc440284602e } ],
  insertedCount: 2,
  insertedIds: [ 565570547d27dc440284602d, 565570547d27dc440284602e ] }
```

Maybe I'll misunderstood mongoDB documentation, but I would like to see the results of above insert in a table view or something (like phpMyAdmin for mySQL). Is something possible for mongoDB? I couldn't find anything about this.

I was also wondering if the insert is running every time I'll open my application and a connect to mongoDB is made?!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't have the concept of "table", instead it stores objects in a format called BSON (it's JSON) and you can't rappresent easily an object in a table.

#### MongoDB Admin UI

If you want something like phpmyadmin for MongoDB you could use

[mongo-express](https://github.com/andzdroid/mongo-express)

if you want a complete list you could take a look at

[MongoDB Admin UIs](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually mongoDB is nosql database it doesn't uses tables to store data. It uses json. But if you want to see all the documents in a table like format then you can use a application called 'Robo 3T'. It displays your json data in  a table like structure but still it is a json data. It doesn't store data in a table.